# Getting image from folder using PHP: Code working and getting image path but img not being placed into HTML

Tags: php, css, glob

I've been looking all over the place but can't seem to find an issue quite like mine. Maybe I haven't been putting together the right keywords; but perhaps I'll have more luck just explaining my issue.

I've put together the following little code:

```
    $image_types = array('gif','png','jpg');
    $recent = array();

    foreach($image_types as $image_type) {
        foreach(glob('first/second/*.'.$image_type) as $filename){
            $recent[$filename] = time() - filemtime($filename);
        }
    }

    $recent = array_keys($recent, min($recent));
    $recent_img = $recent[0];
```

What it's supposed to do is look into a specific folder and find the latest image and, later, place it into the webpage. What it *does do* is find the latest image, path and all. So everything is working up to there. If I `echo` `$recent_img` I get the latest image's `src`, so obviously I'd want to place the following code right after: `<img src="<?php echo $recent_img ?>" />` and I should get the image. Surely enough, everything works fine, even up to the point locating within the HTML an `<img>` that refers to the image I need. HOWEVER, there's something going haywire at this point!

If `glob()` is set to the path `first` alone, the code works entirely: the image is shown in the website. But with the `second` folder added, it does everything except show the image on the website.

So I go to the result website and check the source code and the image code is as follows:

```
    <img src="first/second/img.jpg" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0">
```

Notice the `display:none!important` the `visibility:hidden!important` etc., almost like the CSS is set to do everything it can to avoid showing the image. Including setting the width and height to 0 when the image is obviously not 0 x 0 pixs. (Just in case: nor is there any instance in my style sheet which would result in setting everything to 0 and hidden and etc. on any image in my project.)

However, as I said, this does not happen when the path only has the one part, the folder `first`. I've tried putting all the images from one folder into the other and still the issue remains. I've edited the CSS values on the spot in Chrome and still nothing.

It seems like an absurd issue to have because nothing is changing except the code is looking for a file inside of a folder that is inside a parent folder. Moreover because the code actually works to the point of showing the file I need and its path but not the file itself.

### Online trial example for you guys to see and TEMP solution or, rather, 'workaround'.

I hate working around an issue. It usually complicates things and/or makes them messy. First of all, in this case it is an organization issue. It's much better to have ALL images in one folder and then make sub-folders for different kinds. Having many image folders floating about the root is not a good idea to me. Second, it seems absurd to have to use a 'workaround' when there seems no logic in the error. Third, I really would like to learn what is going on and not turn this into a PHP Bermuda Triangle. So please don't take my TEMP solution as me giving up, and please continue the synergy of this wonderful place, where no doubt at some point we'll arrive to a solution.

At any rate, the 'workaround' you've probably already guessed is to place the `second` folder in the same directory as the `first` folder, which is the root. So this should solve that specific issue. But it's not a genial solution if you ask me.

I've been asked to upload an online trial of the issue and I've done so [>>HERE<<](http://www.procesosaltavida.com/trial.php). You'll be able to see the same code looking for the latest image in `first/second/` and in `first/`, and you'll see that one works marvelously where the other mysteriously flops!

**QUESTION: Just occurred to me. Could it have something to do with the length of the path name? I.e. `first/` is O.K. but `first/second/` is too long? Doesn't make much sense taking into consideration that the retrieval of info from the path is successful, and the issue is rather on the side of the HTML outcome, but I have since tried placing the `second` folder in the root and gave it a 10-letter name and the issue was recreated. This, however, only happened in WAMP localhost, as when I uploaded everything online, the length didn't seem to matter. However, even online, as you can see from my [LINK](http://www.procesosaltavida.com/trial.php) the first issue remains.**

Comment: Change `img` to `a` and see whether the browser understand the URL.  Maybe a `/` on the beginning is missing or something like that. It also enables you to make sure your `PHP` code is correct.

Comment: Hi, Sheric. I've followed your recommendation and, sure enough, the path is 100% correct. I set it up as `a` and then click on it and the image appears. But, still, when I turn it back into `img`, same issue continues. But, remember, if I look for images in the `first/` path and not the `first/second/` path, everything works fine!

Comment: Can we see this live somehow?

Comment: Is it uploaded somewhere to pass me a link? Use firebug on firefox to check why it is like that. You can inspect the img tag in firebug so that you can see the whether the image is loaded and whether there is some css code that is hiding it. and more important, where exactly the img is.

Comment: Hey, Sheric, I've edited my response to add at the bottom a link to an uploaded trial of this issue. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: It is funny but it is working fine for me. I can see both of the images and none of the weird CSS styles. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I know I'm late to this party, but FYI I see both images. You have a cacheing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try retrieve the src and update using jquery:

```
$.get('image.php').success(function(src) {
    $('#myimg').attr('src',src);
});
```

Comment: Hey, Jeff, thanks for the response! Unfortunately, it's not working for me. I get a blank `src='____'`, which points back to the localhost. On the other hand, remember that the issue doesn't come up if the path is `first/` instead of `first/second/`.

Comment: do you `echo` the image link? or else, it will not return as the function argument src.

Comment: Yes, Jeff, I've done so, but unfortunately no positive response. I even changed `.attr` to `.prop` as I've been having some issue with the former since its deprecation. My question is: this jQuery code aims at getting the PHP data and then dynamically changing the image `src`. But wouldn't one want to do this, say, if the element were being created before the `src` was worked out and therefore ended up having none? And since PHP is server-side, could there be an instance in which this is the issue?

Comment: In this case, however, if one checks the source code it is clear that the `src` is being attached. But something else happens. And only if the path is a child folder.